Error signing email with eID certificate using Outlook365
When I try to sign an email using Outlook365, I get an error message stating there is no email address associated with the certificate present on the eID smartcard (note: I can use my eID to sign Word and PDF documents).

It is normal not to have an email associated with an eID certificate; instead Outlook should be asking to select a card reader where the smart card is inserted into, then ask for the PIN code (this isn't happening)
I have tried everything I have found on the net, actions and verifications, without any success, and get the same error message. That includes:

adding the certificate via Outlook Trust Center (which I cannot Publish to GAL since there is no button supposedly because the email server is of type IMAP/SMTP) in order to have the SIGN button in the email compose window
trying to edit the security settings when the error appears after clicking the send button without any success since the error is there everytime
adding the certificate in the Windows Certificate Manager (where the certificate issued to me by my company associated with my professional email address is) which had no effect on the issue
updating the eID driver to the latest version
adding the root certificates related to the eID to the Windows Certificate Manager
updating Outlook client to the latest version
verifying that the certificate is still valid, and it is still valid



Does anybody have experience with this problem?

When the dialog box pops up, have you tried setting the signing certificate via: Change Security Settings... → Security setting: Change Settings... → Signing Certificate: Choose...

Follow the steps in this article to re-add your signature and check for any discrepancie : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/secure-messages-by-using-a-digital-signature-549ca2f1-a68f-4366-85fa-b3f4b5856fc6#:~:text=On%20the%20File%20menu%2C%20click%20Options%20%3E%20Trust,use.%20Compose%20your%20message%2C%20and%20then%20send%20it.

@JW0914 Yes I have tried that already, it part of everything I have found on the net.

@Soki I have followed those step already, it part of everything I have found on the net.

@Toady Please edit your question and add to it what you've tried
